# Textbox onChange event and Datepicker onSelect conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two text boxes for date fields. User is allowed to enter date in those fields via both jQuery-ui Datepicker and via manually typing through keyboard. The requirement is after entering date in the 1st textbox, the second textbox should get populated with the date exactly 1 year later.I have handled most of the scenarios.
I will try to explain clearly in which scenario I am facing the issue. Suppose I am typing in the date manually from keyboard and suddenly I decide to select a different date from Datepicker instead. In this case the the textbox is not showing the selected date from datepicker. I hope I am able to articulate clearly. My guess is Datepicker's onSelect() event is not getting fired in this particular scenario because of any conflict with the textbox's onChange() event.

```js
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        constrainInput: "true",
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function (date) {

            var parsedDate = parseDate(date);

            var moddate = new Date(Date.parse(parsedDate));

            moddate.setFullYear(moddate.getFullYear() + 1);

            var newDate = moddate.toDateString();

            newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));

            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDate);

            $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', newDate);

        }

    });
    
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,

    });

    var maskConfig = {
        leapday: "29-02-",
        separator: "/",
        showMaskOnHover: false,
        showMaskOnFocus: false,
        placeholder: "00/00/0000"
    }

    $('#datepicker1').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy', maskConfig);
    $('#datepicker2').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy', maskConfig);
    
    $('#datepicker1').on("change",function () {
     
        
            var parsedDate = parseDate($('#datepicker1').val());

            var date = new Date(Date.parse(parsedDate));

            date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);

            var newDate = date.toDateString();

            newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));

            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDate);

            $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', newDate);

    });
    
    function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.split('/');
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker1"/>
<input type="text" id="datepicker2"/>
```

Comment: try to set default date for datepicker1

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any exact fix for this issue. I am currently going with a small hack/workaround. I am hiding the datepicker as soon as user starts typing inside the textbox. I am using the "keyup" event handler.

```js
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        constrainInput: "true",
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function (date) {

            var parsedDate = parseDate(date);

            var moddate = new Date(Date.parse(parsedDate));

            moddate.setFullYear(moddate.getFullYear() + 1);

            var newDate = moddate.toDateString();

            newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));

            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDate);

            $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', newDate);

        }

    });
    
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,

    });

    var maskConfig = {
        leapday: "29-02-",
        separator: "/",
        showMaskOnHover: false,
        showMaskOnFocus: false,
        placeholder: "00/00/0000"
    }

    $('#datepicker1').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy', maskConfig);
    $('#datepicker2').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy', maskConfig);
    
    $('#datepicker1').on("change",function () {
     
        
            var parsedDate = parseDate($('#datepicker1').val());

            var date = new Date(Date.parse(parsedDate));

            date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);

            var newDate = date.toDateString();

            newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));

            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDate);

            $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', newDate);

    });
    
    $('#datepicker1').on('keyup', function() {
     if (this.value.length > 0) {
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker('hide') ;
     }
     else{
     $('#datepicker1').datepicker('show') ;
     }
});

$('#datepicker2').on('keyup', function() {
     if (this.value.length > 0) {
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker('hide') ;
     }
      else{
     $('#datepicker2').datepicker('show') ;
     }
});
    
    function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.split('/');
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker1"/>
<input type="text" id="datepicker2"/>
```